# Backend Internal error: Exception during psi2ir

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, jvm, kodein

I've been trying to use kodein in my android studio and I'm getting this issue

> The root cause org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.ErrorExpressionException was thrown at: org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.ErrorExpressionGenerator.generateErrorCall(ErrorExpressionGenerator.kt:99)
> null: KtCallExpression:
> kodein()
> at
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.CodegenUtil.reportBackendException(CodegenUtil.kt:239)

here is how I'm calling it in activity

> override val kodein by kodein()

I've tried updating all my dependencies, however still no result,

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: in Intellij IDEA IDE when I got the error I had to invalidate cache to resolve the issue. `File` -> `invalidate caches` to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a Kodein issue. this is a kotlin issue. Please try updating your kotlin version.

try `1.6.10`

Answer (score 1):

we need to import **import org.kodein.di.android.kodein** for kodein()

Comment: Instead of bold text, use code snippet to write any command or anything which is to be copy and pasted as it is.